# Why use Type 3 structure for a present situation: "They would have had lots of training...." instead of "They have had lots of training."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, conditional-constructions

This is from a BBC video, in which people in a spacecraft are shown when they are allowed to unbuckle to experience the zero gravity in a spacecraft. [People in a spacecraft](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-66468628) (see:00:24-00:30). The presenter says:

**They would have had lots of training and lots of anticipation and buildup.**

The presenter knows very well that they are trained and are informed about this journey. So why does the presenter use the Type 3 structure as if it was an unreal past which is irreversible. **"They would have had lots of training ......"** instead of **"They have had lots of training ...."**?

Is it because the presenter is making a guess or giving his opinion on how well-informed they might be?

Comment: It's like saying a friend flying to Paris *would have landed by now* when you don't know it, but it makes sense. If she called, then she landed. If there's a pattern of training, then these astronauts *would have had lots of* such training, but you don't that for a fact.

Comment: "To experience zero gravity, they will have lots of training." To experience zero gravity, they would have had lots of training". Here would is the past tense of will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this a narrative resource. I have came up with two possible interpretations (wich are not mutually exclusive):

- **Tentative language**
  The narrator is trying to make the experience more immersive by taking the viewer's point of view, in order to suggest that they are highly likely to have received training (thus, hinting that the narrator is aware of it, or that it can be deduced by the context).
  This is structure is frequently used in documentaries (at least, this is what I feel when I watch documentaries in Spanish, as this kind of structure does appear sometimes).
- **Speech style**
  Documentaries also frequently make use of unusual sentence structures to make the experience more engaging. This interpretation is harder to justify, but I do have an example in mind to share, see if it helps to understand this.

The following quote is from a documentary that is about inhumane working conditions. I do not recall exactly which was the title, but it is not important for our purpose:

> The workers hunched over the vines like ducks, there is no air, making the intense heat all but unbearable.

Which would normally be simply said as

> The workers hunched over the vines, making the intense heat unbearable.

---

## Edit #1

As pointed out by @KateBunting, the given example is not good because I misinterpreted the syntactic structure of the sentence.
A better example follows:

> Then, in a burst of raw power and agility, the lioness springs forward. The chase is on.

Which, in a less convoluted language, could be simply said as:

> Then the lioness springs forward. The chase is on.

Comment: Surely it was the lack of air which made the heat unbearable, so the phrase can't be omitted.

Comment: What you are referring is to the fact that there is some loss of information, what I am referring to is the preservation of coherence even if the clause were to be omitted.

Comment: The sentence makes no sense if the clause is omitted.

Comment: Why would it be? This ellipsis either means that the narrator is leaving the root cause of the unbearable heat as an open topic (left to the reader to ponder about) or it can be infered by context. I can still read this sentence and logically deduce that it has something to do with their previous action. Albeit not knowing the specifics.

Comment: It was not the 'workers hunching over the vines', but the lack of air, that made the heat unbearable.

Comment: OK, I see your point now. I was a bit hasty about making that example (and a bit sketchy) and did not realize that "there is no air" is not a subordinate clause and thus the verb "making" is refering to the clause "there is no air" and not the previous clause to this one. I'll try to think of a better example. Thank you for highlighting this mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148229/discussion-between-jiaze-zhang-and-kate-bunting).

Answer (score 4):

Modals generally have an [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) meaning (about the speaker's knowledge) as well as a [deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) meaning (about possibilities and necessities in the physical or social world).

It is sometimes difficult to know which is being used, but here *would have* is epistemic, and means something like "I expect that they had".